# Inline CSS to make columns

Tags: css, css-float, inline

On my test page for a WordPress theme I want to have two collumns side by side done in CSS. I have tried inline options and various other ways but it doesn't work. http://joshblease.co.uk/wp-content/themes/rounded/test.php this page is what I'm using to check it, basically I want the column with the work "hello" in it to start from the menu bar too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
float:left
```

on both columns, then it should work.

Comment: You can also use inline-block with a vertical-align to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Do you know how I could extend it to be the same size as the left column? It varies in height but to align them is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: That would be a bit more complicated I think - there's a wide range from Javascript to HTML/CSS hacks to do this - try searching for hints with Google. The Faux Columns article (http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) is probably one of the classics, but you might also like "Fluid Width Euqal Height Columns" (http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/). Good luck :)